# Object property only increments once within function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to increment the "count" property on the "product" object using the the "addItemToCart" function. But when I click to add that product to the "Cart" page, it will only increment by 1 the first time but the not each subsequent time. What's the issue?

**ProductDetails.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import "./ProductDetails.css";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
const ProductDetails = (props) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
  const productInfo = products.find(
    (item) => item.name === location.state.name
  );
  const { name, image, price } = productInfo;
  let product = {
    name,
    price,
    count: 0,
  };
  const cartCounter = (counter) => {
    props.setCartCount((counter += 1));
  };

  const cartPriceCounter = (counter) => {
    props.setCartTotal((counter += price));
  };

  const addItemToCart = () => {
    if (!props.cartItems.find((e) => e.name === product.name)) {
      props.setCartItems([...props.cartItems, product]);
    }

    return product.count += 1;
  };

  return (
    <div className="details-container">
      <div className="details-card">
        <img className="details-img" src={image} alt={name} />
        <div className="details-div">
          <h3 className="details-title">{name}</h3>
          <p className="details-price">${price}</p>
          <button
            className="add-to-cart"
            onClick={() => {
              props.setCartCount(cartCounter);
              props.setCartTotal(cartPriceCounter);
              addItemToCart();
            }}
          >
            Add To Cart
          </button>
          {console.log(product.count)}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

**CartItem.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./CartItem.css";

const CartItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="item">
      <p>{props.name}</p>
      <p>{props.itemCount}</p>
      <p>{props.price}</p>
      <p>Delete</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CartItem;
```

**CartPage.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

import CartItem from "../CartItem/CartItem";
import "./CartPage.css";

const CartPage = (props) => {
  const minusItem = (counter) => {
    props.setCartCount((counter -= 1));
  };
  const addItem = (counter) => {
    props.setCartCount((counter += 1));
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="cart-page">
      <h3 className="cart-title">Shopping Cart</h3>
      <div className="cart-info">
        <div className="items-container">
          <div className="items-header">
            <h5>PRODUCT</h5>
            <h5>QUANTITY</h5>
            <h5>PRICE</h5>
          </div>
          {props.cartItems.map((item, id) => {
            return (
              <CartItem
                key={id}
                name={item.name}
                price={item.price}
                itemCount={item.count}
                setCartCount={props.setCartCount}
                minusItem={minusItem}
                addItem={addItem}
                setCartTotal={props.setCartTotal}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
        {console.log(props)}
        <div className="order-summary">
          <h5>Order Summary</h5>
          <hr />
          <h6>Items</h6>
          <p>{props.cartCount}</p>
          <h6>Total Price</h6>
          <p>${props.cartTotal.toFixed(2)}</p>
          <button>Checkout</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CartPage;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not handling the state with the useState hook, and React does not now about the changes (and thus not triggering a new render).

The right way is to use the useState hook to handle the increment in the product, something like this:

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import CartItem from "../CartItem/CartItem";
import "./CartPage.css";

const CartPage = (props) => {
const [amount, setAmount] = useState(1);


  
  return (
    <div className="cart-page">
      <h3 className="cart-title">Shopping Cart</h3>
      <div className="cart-info">
        <div className="items-container">
          <div className="items-header">
            <h5>PRODUCT</h5>
            <h5>QUANTITY</h5>
            <h5>PRICE</h5>
          </div>
          {props.cartItems.map((item, id) => {
            return (
              <CartItem
                key={id}
                name={item.name}
                price={item.price}
                itemCount={item.count}
                setCartCount={setAmount(prevAmount=> prevAmount + 1)}
                minusItem={setAmount(prevAmount=> prevAmoun -1)}}
                addItem={addItem}
                setCartTotal={props.setCartTotal}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
        {console.log(props)}
        <div className="order-summary">
          <h5>Order Summary</h5>
          <hr />
          <h6>Items</h6>
          <p>{props.cartCount}</p>
          <h6>Total Price</h6>
          <p>${props.cartTotal.toFixed(2)}</p>
          <button>Checkout</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CartPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you declare `product` inside a function component. So it will re-create when component re-render, You should declare it as a `state` and update by `setState`.

```
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({
    name,
    price,
    count: 0,
  });

  ...

  setProduct(preState => ({
    ...preState,
    count: preState.count + 1
  }))
```

Comment: This works, thanks! The only problem is when I switch to another page, the count resets to 0. I can probably store the incremented count using localStorage, but I'm not sure where I should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should never mutate the state. Prefer to do that instead:

```
props.setCartCount({counter: counter + 1});
```